# How to use small icons in kupfer?

Tags: pygtk, kupfer

I don't like the large (128px) icons used in Kupfer, how can I configure it to use smaller icons?

The [theming documentation](http://kaizer.se/wiki/kupfer/GTKTheming.html) suggests it can be done.

I've duplicated the built in `customtheme.py` plugin into `~/.local/share/kupfer/plugins/mytheme.py` and tried adding this code to the "dark" definition:

```
## force small icons
gtk-icon-sizes="kupfer-small=24,24:kupfer-large=24,24"
```

But that doesn't seem to change the icon size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem, so I googled,And it turned out, that I could edit this file:

```
sudo nano /usr/share/kupfer/kupfer/icons.py
```

Changed variable

```
LARGE_SZ = 128
```

to

```
LARGE_SZ = 32
```

I hope it was helpful. Greetings from Debian!